# Открыть новое окно в kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, виджет

Подскажите как мне при нажатии кнопки "Aply" открывать новое окно класса SecondWind ??

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 400)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)

class SecondWind(Widget):
    def wind(self):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', spacing = 2)

        bl.add_widget(Button(text = '1'))
        bl.add_widget(Button(text = '2'))
        bl.add_widget(Button(text = '3'))

        return bl


class TrainApp(App):
    dic = {}
    sw = SecondWind()

    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical',spacing = 5, size_hint = (.8,.8 ))

        self.key = TextInput( background_color = [1,0.3,0.5,1],multiline = False)
        self.value = TextInput(text = '2nd Name', background_color = [1,0.3,0.5,1],multiline = False )

        bl.add_widget(self.key)
        bl.add_widget(self.value)
        bl.add_widget(Button(text = 'Aply', on_press = self.aply))

        al.add_widget(bl)

        return al

    def aply(self, instance):
        if self.key.text != '':
            self.dic[self.key.text] = self.value.text
        else:
            self.dic['Name'] = self.value.text
        print(self.dic)






if __name__ == '__main__':
    TrainApp().run()
```

Comment: Если хочется открыть именно модельное окно, то нужно использовать ModalView. Если же нужно открыть новый экран, то нужно использовать ScreenManager и Screen. Пример модельного окна есть в kivy/examples.